# Azure SQL database connection with pyodbc

Tags: python, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, pyodbc

I am trying to connect to Azure SQL Database using pyodbc and getting the error:

> pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('28000', '[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'adminc'. (18456)(SQLDriverConnect); [28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot open database "fueldb-cloud" requested by the login. The login failed. (4060); [28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid connection string attribute (0); [28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'adminc'. (18456); [28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot open database "fueldb-cloud" requested by the login. The login failed. (4060); [28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid connection string attribute (0)')

I am using the following connection string :

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER='+server+';PORT=1433;DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+password)
```

I am able to connect to it in SSMS but not via python.

Comment: check this if it helps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/connect-query-python?tabs=windows

Comment: Tried this but didn't helped.

Comment: Does `username` and/or `password` contain any semicolons or other potentially problematic characters?

Comment: @GordThompson No. But changing the database name somehow resolved the issue, which I have no idea how.

Comment: I am having the same issue right now and could not find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

changing the database name somehow resolved the issue, which I have no idea how